# (400) Bad Request even when quotas are maxed out

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I have a c# winform app.

I am invoking a web service on my server.

In essence I am uploading a byte array.

I know about quotas and I have set them up (I think!) correctly.

I have tried passing zero bytes and the call passes OK.

In my test I am trying to upload 719280 bytes.

I get 400 bad request error.

This is my web.config for the service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ThrottledBehavior">
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="0.00:00:30" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" 
                             maxConcurrentSessions="50" 
                             maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Sync" behaviorConfiguration="ThrottledBehavior">
        <endpoint address="Uploader.svc" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingEndPoint" 
                  contract="ISync" name="wsUploader"  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingEndPoint" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 messageEncoding="Mtom" 
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Refer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx

Comment: @VigneshKumar Hi, thanks for your link.  Whilst it was interesting it does not actually tell me what is wrong in my config file?  I am hosting only 1 service so..?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - What happens if you pass in a small byte array (something that is greater than 0, but not very large)?  Does that work?

Comment: @Tim thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that  (1 byte) and it works OK.  It was a good thing to try though.  thanks

Comment: @geek Hi, yes I noticed that - thanks. I just put that in. Restarted IIS. rebuilt my project and updated the service from the client. Same error I am afraid. What a pain.  Is there anything in IIS that can overwrite this setting? ( I am going to take a look now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

increase "maxRequestLength" value in

```
<httpRuntime
      executionTimeout="1200"
      maxRequestLength="1024000"
      appRequestQueueLimit="300" />
```

**Update**
go to binding configuration and change transfer mode to **Streamed**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingEndPoint" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 transferMode="Streamed"

                 messageEncoding="Mtom" 
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.  I have already set this in my web config file though:  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on tracing (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)), maybe that'll reveal some details.
Add this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi,  yes I have just been doing that :). The error lies  with the settings my definition for 'ThrottledBehavior'. In particular my value for maxConcurrentInstances.  The error i traced was that this setting has been exceeded.  I am createing a new behaviour without any throtterling and I am about to test :)

Answer (score 1):

my particular issue was that I was using Throttled behaviour. This setting is OK for small data but not large. So changing this binding to normal/standard behaviour like so:

```
    <behavior name="NormalBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
```

instead of using this:

```
    <behavior name="ThrottledBehavior">
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="0.00:00:30" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" maxConcurrentSessions="50" maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
```

worked for me.

The essence here is that the 'serviceThrottling' has been removed.  I could have kept this in but then I would have to increase the maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentSessions and maxConcurrentInstances which I did try but was counter productive to throttled behaviour and thus took a lot longer to process.

Thanks to everyone giving their time to this

Comment: So, what you actually did is stripping out some `<serviceThrottling>`-node out of your `<behavior>`-node?

Comment: maybe you should point that out in your answer, to make this point clear to other readers

Comment: Does not my answer state/imply that?

Comment: It looks like some quite default behavior-node. If you just skim your answer, you are likely to oversee that. But it's just a suggestion ;)

Comment: Always open to suggestions.  This 400 error seems to have a lot of different resolutions so I do hope it helps anyone out. Thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44052/discussion-between-jme-and-andrew-simpson)